# Ive made this code to create multiple files in a loop but all i get at the end is TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Tags: python

```
i = 1
ll=['a','b','c','e','f']

for it in ll:
    i_str=str
    filename=(i_str, '.txt')
    f=open(filename,'w')
    f.write("i dont think you can close this mate :)")
    f.close()
    i=i+1
```

this code is supposed to create multiple files which contain the same thing but it just doesnt seem to be working correctly. At the end i get this

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the strings.

```py
filename=(i_str, '.txt')
```

Is a `tuple` with `str` and `'.txt'`. By the way, the line above this does not seem correct. Did you mean to put `str(i)`?

```py
filename = i_str + '.txt'
```

Is probably what you wanted to create a single string, provided your `i_str` is also a string.

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'str' - thats what im now getting, it just doesnt make any sense at all. Sorry im new to Python

Comment: You need to fix `i_str` first. I asked above whether you meant to put `i_str = str(i)` which would allow adding a string to another string.